# Asynchronous view call in backbone.js when model is updated

Tags: html, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm trying to make a demo application for practicing backbone.js.

In my app architecture I first designed the model and inside it wrote a code for parsing a JSON file and storing those records in localStorage and then populating model's attribute `hotelsdata` with the first 10 records of localStorage.
And then whenever I'm calling the `backbone.view.extend()` I'm fetching the data from model object.

Now, what I want to do is whenever my model is updated my view must also be updated from the new values in the model. I've already tried

```
model.on('change',function())
```

trigger but when I'm calling the `view.render()` method on the `change` event my page is being updated, but during the period of adding of records on the page my scroll is not working.

So, can anyone please suggest some way in which I can call that `view.render()` method asynchronously so that my page's scroll would not be affected during the pressing time of `view.render()`.

In short when my view is being updated the scrolling of the page must work.

Comment: Have you tried timeouts? Or being that your using Backbone and therefore also underscore.js have you played with the _.defer function http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#defer ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem of, how we can call it?, *brutal render* :)..

I should see your `render()` method to confirm it, but I think in your render you are **removing from the DOM a big portion of the page** and then recreating it again. This could cause your scroll to messup. And there is not any *asynchronous* behavior that can help you.

You should recreate the subelements of your View one by one to have a sweet scroll feeling.

*(Show us your `render()` method if I'm completely confuse)*